# HackerRank Mininum Difference RunTimeError

Tags: java

My code throws a run-time error, can anyone explain why? My solution envolves adding to an array the differences between `j` and `i`, and then find the minimum of the two, only to return it. But for some reason it gives me a timeout error. The question is question is this:

> We define the distance between two array values as the number of indices between the two values. Given `A` find the minimum distance between any pair of equal elements in the array. If no such value exists, print `-1` The minimum difference is calculated by the difference between index `j` and index `i`

```
 static int minimumDistances(int[] a) {

    int[] difference = new int[a.length];
    int lowest = 0;
    boolean pairFound = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {

            for(int l = 0; l < difference.length; l++) {

                if(a[i] == a[j]) {

                    difference[l] = j - i;
                    pairFound = true;

                } else if(pairFound == false) {

                    lowest = -1;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    if(pairFound == true) {

        lowest = difference[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < difference.length; i++) {

            if(difference[i] < lowest) {

                lowest = difference[i];

            }

        }

    }

    return lowest;

}
```

Comment: You should really describe your solution, give example inputs and outputs, and paste output of the error you are receiving.

Comment: And what kind of "runtime error" does it throw? IIRC, HackerRank runs tests against your code and those may fail when your solution takes too long. Are you sure you don't just need to optimize?

Comment: Why not check the "discussion" section on that question? An O(N^2) solution is surely unacceptable. Hint: lookup "two-pointer technique". Also, learn to use a debugger. You won't get far without one.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and check to see if this works:

```
int[] difference = new int[a.length];
```

Comment: That makes me fail test case 1. For some reason pairFound becomes true

Answer (score 0):

You are looping 3 times, that is (n³) too slow. Try a different approach.
Here is my code using streams.

```
static int minimumDistances(int[] a) {

    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> a[i]));

    return map.entrySet().stream().filter(m -> m.getValue().size() > 1)
            .map(m -> m.getValue().stream()
                    .reduce((acc,val)-> Math.abs(acc - val)).get())
            .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).min().orElse(-1);
    
}
```